# $|detA|=1$, $A$ is unitary?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is an n by n complex matrix with $|det(A)|=1$, then $A$ is unitary.  ??

I think this statement is false, but I can't seem to find an example to show this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider a matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda > 1$ and $1/\lambda$, (this is as simple as the 2x2 diagonal matrix with these entries). Then this matrix cannot be unitary as you have a vector with $Av = \lambda v$

Answer (score 3):

$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ is indeed a counterexample. The statement is true only for $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 
0 &1/2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Then $\det A = -1$, but notice that:
$$
Ae_1 = 2e_1
$$
So that:
$$
\|Ae_1\| = 2 \|e_1\| = 2 \neq \|e_1\| = 1
$$
So $A$ cannot be unitary.